# Can QR codes be used to invite someone to send me an iMessage?

Tags: messages, url, ios

I have tried messages//emailaddress but I am told that it just opens the Messages app on iPhones, not a new message to the user (on my Mac it opens that specific users thread).

Answer (score 1):

In Theory, yes.

You just need to create an SMS QR Code to send a message to a number that is associated with an iMessage account.

Messages will do the rest to confirm that it is a valid iMessage account.

Search online for "SMS QR Code" for examples.

Comment: iMessage, not SMS. My iMessage account isn't connected to a phone number.

Comment: If your iMessage account is an email and not a number, then do the same thing, but use your email address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, QR-Codes can be used. You just need to use this url-scheme for the QR-Codes:

For phone numbers:

```
sms://+0112345678901
```

For mail-addresses:

```
sms://tcook@apple.com
```